# Python beat interval tracking

Tags: python, python-3.x, librosa

Is there a way using Python to track the beat intervals of an instrument in a song? For example... 1+ 3+4.
I have tried the following code...

```
y, sr = librosa.load("Audio\sweetchild_guitar_intro.wav")       

onset_envelope = librosa.onset.onset_strength(y, sr)
onsets = librosa.onset.onset_detect(onset_envelope=onset_envelope)

tempo, beats = librosa.beat.beat_track(onset_envelope=onset_envelope)
beat_times = librosa.frames_to_time(beats)

print(f"{tempo}\n{beats}\n{beat_times}")
print(len(beat_times))
```

However, the variable '`beat_times`' prints 24, where the total number of notes/onsets in my audio file is 47, so I'm not exactly sure on what this figure is giving me. I have also experimented with the other variables in this code, but have not found anything.

Any and all help is much appreciated! Thanks

Edit

So I have found the meaning of the following variables...
`tempo` -> This is the bpm value
`beat_times` -> This is when a beat occurs relative to the `onset_envelope` values
`len(beat_times)` -> How many times a beat occurs.

However, I still cannot find how to get the interval timing of the notes?